# ESP32 WiFi.status() always returns WL_DICSONNECTED (STA_MODE)

Tags: c++, wifi, esp32

I've spent a many hours trying to solve this.

I have added multiple attempts, tried to WiFi.disconnect() before Wifi.begin().
Nothing works: `status`remains to be `WL_DISCONNECTED` (0x06).

```
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
for(;;) {
        attempt++;

        Wifi.begin(ssid, password);
        wl_status_t status = WiFi.status();
        String m = connectionStatusMessage(status);
        log("Connection attempt %d: status is%s", attempt, m.c_str());

        if (status == WL_CONNECTED) {       
            Serial.println();
            success("connected (WL_CONNECTED)");
            information();
            break;
        }
```

[UPDATE]
Note: I use a ESP-WROOM-32 devkit package. The ESP32 sdk being the latest stable available on PlatformIO. I tested others devkits such a one from Az-Delivery too.

Comment: That works just fine for me. Are you sure ssid and password are ok and the WiFi is in range?

Comment: Yep, I know it should. My credentials have been double checked.

Comment: does WiFiScan example  show your AP? try WiFi.disconnect() before WiFi.begin(). use WiFi.waitForConnectResult(), then test WiFi.status()

Comment: Is it disconnected or does it connect and mis-report its status? Are you sure the SSID you're trying to connect to is a 2.4GHz network and not a a 5GHz network? When you run a wifi scanner on the ESP does it show the network?

Comment: The scan is ok and list all avail ssid. The SSID/password have been double-checked. 2.4 checked as well.

Comment: Add `yield()` into the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a solution: The fix is to use `WiFi.waitForConnectResult()` instead of `WiFi.status()`.

I initially thought it was a bug but as @juraj mentioned, and by examinination of the WiFi code, it is a matter of waiting for the status to come. And the waitFoConnectionResult() does just that. Hence the result.

Working code as follows:

```cpp
   WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
   for(;;) {
        attempt++;

        Wifi.begin(ssid, password);

        // >>>> the fix <<<<<
        uint8_t status = WiFi.waitForConnectResult();

        String m = connectionStatusMessage(status);
        log("Connection attempt %d: status is%s", attempt, m.c_str());

        if (status == WL_CONNECTED) {       
            Serial.println();
            success("connected (WL_CONNECTED)");
            information();
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Not doubting there's a bug, but that's odd.... the `waitForConnectResult()` method calls the `status()` method with some surrounding logic and a timeout - see at https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/16f4b0f5baf4d8fe4c679f478dc259aadbb3b68a/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFiSTA.cpp#L379

Comment: @romkey, it is not a bug. `begin` is async

Comment: “**Waiting longer (for at least 6> seconds)**” was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea: `WiFi.begin(ssid, password)` should be called only once. Put it before the loop:

```
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
        
for(;;) {
        attempt++;

        wl_status_t status = WiFi.status();
        String m = connectionStatusMessage(status);
        log("Connection attempt %d: status is%s", attempt, m.c_str());

        if (status == WL_CONNECTED) {       
            Serial.println();
            success("connected (WL_CONNECTED)");
            information();
            break;
        } 
}
```

Comment: Already did that. My first rev code was as simple as that. Then I have added repetitions, delays, etc.

Comment: Enable Kernel debugging. This should get you additional information on the console. (In the Arduino IDE that is "Tools->Core Debug Level->Verbose")